# Facing no such file or directory error when generate password encrypted excel file in spring boot

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, encryption

**The below code is used to create a password protected excel file.**

```
    1.POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
    2.EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
    3.Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
    4.enc.confirmPassword("pass");
    5.Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    6.Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet1");
    7.sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("test123");
    8.OutputStream encos = enc.getDataStream(fs);
    9.workbook.write(encos);
    10.workbook.close();
    11.OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("provawrite.xlsx");
    12.fs.writeFilesystem(os);
    13.os.close();
```

**I am using the below dependencies.**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>        
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>       
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>      
            <version>3.12</version>     
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**This Code is working perfectly fine in Spring Tool Suite (localhost) but when I push the same code in an external server and run it at that time it showing below error. (This error is generated on Line number 8)**

```
    2020-01-03 18:20:06.553 ERROR 2847 --- [io-8080-exec-44] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [No such file or directory]
    java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
            at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
            at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
            at org.apache.poi.util.TempFile$DefaultTempFileCreationStrategy.createTempFile(TempFile.java:105) ~[poi-3.12.jar:3.12]
            at org.apache.poi.util.TempFile.createTempFile(TempFile.java:60) ~[poi-3.12.jar:3.12]
            at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.ChunkedCipherOutputStream.(ChunkedCipherOutputStream.java:60) ~[poi-3.12.jar:3.12]
            at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.agile.AgileEncryptor$AgileCipherOutputStream.(AgileEncryptor.java:419) ~[poi-ooxml-3.12.jar:3.12]
            at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.agile.AgileEncryptor.getDataStream(AgileEncryptor.java:220) ~[poi-ooxml-3.12.jar:3.12]
            at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.Encryptor.getDataStream(Encryptor.java:56) ~[poi-3.12.jar:3.12]
            at com.DailyReportController.welcome1(DailyReportController.java:50) ~[classes/:1.0]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.47]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.47]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.47]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: have you checked the applications user permissions

Comment: @ThomasAndolf can you please tell me which permission required?

Comment: How could i tell you when you have provided none information about, what type of application, how it is run, where it is run, what operating system? As what user is the application running, what current permission does it have, etc etc

Comment: All you have written is `but when I push the same code in an external server and run it` which says nothing

Comment: I have created API in spring boot. On calling generate-excel API this code will execute. The external server is deployed on centOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. It's a dependency issue.
Please add the below dependency.

```
<dependency>        
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>       
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>        
    <version>3.12</version>     
</dependency>
```